# Select from a DataTable from a Module

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've got a DataTable in DataSet which is filled on Form's `Load` event with some data from an SQL database.

I've added a Module where I am creating a function which will utilize the data from the DataTable.

Whilst I am able to get row data from Form's code, I am not able to access it from within the Module which I am guessing has something to do with references to a DataSet/DataTable.

I am typing below from top of my head...

```
Dim dt as Datatable
Dim dr() as Datarow

Dim DataSet1 as Dataset = New DataSet1

dt = DataSet1.comm_rates

dr = dt.select("fieldName='somevalue'")

Return a = dr(0)("fieldA")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In what code block is this? Edit you question to put the code in it's context. For now, use the `Friend` or `Public` modifiers to make an object accessible in your entire project,

Comment: You can't really state, 'I am typing below from top of my head...'.  If you want to resolve the error you have, pseudo code is probably not sufficient.  Please can you provide the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing DataSet1 is inside Class Form1, qualify your reference, e.g

```
Dim ds1 = Form1.DataSet1
     dt = ds1.comm_rates
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. I'm a Stack Overflow Newbie like you. I think we are supposed to Upvote the answer which hits the spot

Comment: I have done it but it doesn't do anything as apparently I haven't got enough reputation...

Comment: well it seems my reputation has gone up so you must have done something cheers